Shading part of a table
I'm working on a table using multirow to make the word "Region" span two rows in the first cell. However, I think the way I'm applying the shading is causing the text to get cut off, with only the top part visible. I've tried several alternatives but haven't yet found a solution.
This is my MWE:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12.0pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\definecolor{copper1}{RGB}{203,109,81}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l l l l l l l l }
\hline
    \rowcolor{copper1} % Aplica el color de fondo a la fila completa
    \multirow{2}{*}{\centering \textbf{\textcolor{white}{Region}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c }{\cellcolor{copper1}} & \multicolumn{6}{c }{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{Recycling input rate}}} \\ \cline{3-8}
    \rowcolor{copper1} % Continúa el color de fondo en la siguiente fila
    \textbf{\textcolor{white}{~}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{~}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2013}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2015}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2017}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2019}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2021}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2022}} \\ \hline
    East Asia and Pacific & & 32\% & 29\% & 30\% & 28\% & 28\% & 28\% \\ \hline
    Europe and Central Asia & & 44\% & 45\% & 47\% & 48\% & 51\% & 48\% \\ \hline
    Latin America and The Caribbean & & 24\% & 29\% & 29\% & 30\% & 29\% & 29\% \\ \hline
    Middle East and North Africa & & 19\% & 19\% & 20\% & 22\% & 24\% & 24\% \\ \hline
    North America & & 34\% & 33\% & 32\% & 34\% & 33\% & 34\% \\ \hline
    South Asia & & 50\% & 55\% & 52\% & 52\% & 52\% & 52\% \\ \hline
    Sub-Saharan Africa & & 28\% & 25\% & 45\% & 41\% & 39\% & 43\% \\ \hline
    World & & 34\% & 33\% & 34\% & 33\% & 33\% & 33\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



See that question.

Here is a possibility with nicematrix

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\definecolor{copper1}{RGB}{203,109,81}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{llllllll}[hlines={1,3-11}]
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=2, rowcolor=copper1, color=white, bold]{}
    \Block{2-1}{Region} && \Block{1-6}{Recycling input rate} \\
     && 2013 & 2015 & 2017 & 2019 & 2021 & 2022 \\
    East Asia and Pacific & & 32\% & 29\% & 30\% & 28\% & 28\% & 28\% \\ 
    Europe and Central Asia & & 44\% & 45\% & 47\% & 48\% & 51\% & 48\% \\ 
    Latin America and The Caribbean & & 24\% & 29\% & 29\% & 30\% & 29\% & 29\% \\ 
    Middle East and North Africa & & 19\% & 19\% & 20\% & 22\% & 24\% & 24\% \\ 
    North America & & 34\% & 33\% & 32\% & 34\% & 33\% & 34\% \\ 
    South Asia & & 50\% & 55\% & 52\% & 52\% & 52\% & 52\% \\ 
    Sub-Saharan Africa & & 28\% & 25\% & 45\% & 41\% & 39\% & 43\% \\ 
    World & & 34\% & 33\% & 34\% & 33\% & 33\% & 33\% \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


With tabularray package the code is short and simple:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12.0pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\definecolor{copper1}{RGB}{203,109,81}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = 4pt,
             colspec = {l *{6}{X[c, si={table-format=2.0{\,\%}}]} },
             row{1,2}= {guard, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=copper1},
             cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{c},
             cell{1}{2} = {c=6}{c},
             cell{3-Z}{2-Z}= {appto={\,\%}},
             }
    \toprule
Region  &  Recycling input rate
                &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \midrule[fg=white]
        & 2013  & 2015  & 2017  & 2019  & 2021  & 2022  \\
East Asia and Pacific 
        &   32  &   29  &   30  &   28  &   28  &   8   \\ 
Europe and Central Asia 
        &   44  &   45  &   47  &   48  &   51  &   48  \\
Latin America and The Caribbean 
        &   24  &   29  &   29  &   30  &   29  &   29  \\ 
Middle East and North Africa 
        &   19  &   19  &   20  &   22  &   24  &   24  \\ 
North America 
        &   34  &   33  &   32  &   34  &   33  &   34  \\ 
South Asia 
        &   50  &   55  &    52 &   52  &   52  &   52  \\ 
Sub-Saharan Africa
        &   28  &   25  &   45  &   41  &   39  &   43  \\ 
World   &   34  &   33  &   34  &   33  &   33  &   33  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



The (very good) answer provided by Sandy G. shows how to construct such tabular with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
In this answer, I only wanted to show that, when you replace the environment {tabular} by an environment {NiceTabular} (with the key [color-inside]), you have directly a solution of your problem.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12.0pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\definecolor{copper1}{RGB}{203,109,81}
 
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ l l l l l l l l }[color-inside]
\hline
    \rowcolor{copper1} % Aplica el color de fondo a la fila completa
    \multirow{2}{*}{\centering \textbf{\textcolor{white}{Region}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c }{\cellcolor{copper1}} & \multicolumn{6}{c }{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{Recycling input rate}}} \\ \cline{3-8}
    \rowcolor{copper1} % Continúa el color de fondo en la siguiente fila
    \textbf{\textcolor{white}{~}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{~}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2013}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2015}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2017}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2019}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2021}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{2022}} \\ \hline
    East Asia and Pacific & & 32\% & 29\% & 30\% & 28\% & 28\% & 28\% \\ \hline
    Europe and Central Asia & & 44\% & 45\% & 47\% & 48\% & 51\% & 48\% \\ \hline
    Latin America and The Caribbean & & 24\% & 29\% & 29\% & 30\% & 29\% & 29\% \\ \hline
    Middle East and North Africa & & 19\% & 19\% & 20\% & 22\% & 24\% & 24\% \\ \hline
    North America & & 34\% & 33\% & 32\% & 34\% & 33\% & 34\% \\ \hline
    South Asia & & 50\% & 55\% & 52\% & 52\% & 52\% & 52\% \\ \hline
    Sub-Saharan Africa & & 28\% & 25\% & 45\% & 41\% & 39\% & 43\% \\ \hline
    World & & 34\% & 33\% & 34\% & 33\% & 33\% & 33\% \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thank you very much guys! That works perfectly.

Zarko provided a booktabs and siunitx approach.  I would take things a bit further: "Recycling input" should move to the table's caption, allowing us to remove the multirow.  Removing the horizontal lines except for the top allows us to remove the shading, making the table easier to read.  Changing "rate" to "percentage" allows us to remove the % from the table.  This all results in less ink in the table, making it more readable.

If the regions were shorter, it would help to transpose the table, so that you could more easily see how consistent the numbers are (it's easier to scan down a column than across a row).  Unfortunately, that would require abbreviating or rotating the region labels, neither of which is helpful.

If your entries weren't all two digits, you would want siunitx and its column type.  (Notice how the 8 in the top right of Zarko's answer aligns correctly with the rest of its column.)  The code for these images:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Recycling input percentage}
\begin{tabular}{ l cccccc }
\toprule
Region & 2013 & 2015 & 2017 & 2019 & 2021 & 2022 \\ \midrule
    East Asia and Pacific & 32 & 29 & 30 & 28 & 28 & 28 \\
    Europe and Central Asia & 44 & 45 & 47 & 48 & 51 & 48 \\
    Latin America and The Caribbean & 24 & 29 & 29 & 30 & 29 & 29 \\
    Middle East and North Africa & 19 & 19 & 20 & 22 & 24 & 24 \\
    North America & 34 & 33 & 32 & 34 & 33 & 34 \\
    South Asia & 50 & 55 & 52 & 52 & 52 & 52 \\
    Sub-Saharan Africa & 28 & 25 & 45 & 41 & 39 & 43 \\
    World & 34 & 33 & 34 & 33 & 33 & 33 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Recycling input percentage by year}
\begin{tabular}{ l cccccccc }
\toprule
Year & EAP & ECA & LAC & MENA & NA & SA & SSA & World \\\midrule
2013 & 32 & 44 & 24 & 19 & 34 & 50 & 28 & 34 \\
2015 & 29 & 45 & 29 & 19 & 33 & 55 & 25 & 33 \\
2017 & 30 & 47 & 29 & 20 & 32 & 52 & 45 & 34 \\
2019 & 28 & 48 & 30 & 22 & 34 & 52 & 45 & 33 \\
2021 & 28 & 51 & 29 & 24 & 33 & 52 & 39 & 33 \\
2022 & 28 & 48 & 29 & 24 & 34 & 52 & 43 & 33 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thanks for the comment. I agree with the idea of removing % from the data.
